# How can I integrate wordpress into magento 2 project in valet plus?

Tags: wordpress, magento2, valet

I am using Valet+ for my Magento projects.
Currently I’m trying to add WP integration for M2 project. I put  wordpress copy into pub/wp/ directory and want to go through the installation process, but I’m receiving 404 error when I’m trying to access url like https://magento2.test/wp/
Could anyone advice for it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom valet driver for it.

Copy Magento2ValetDriver.php into magento root directory and rename it to LocalValetDriver.php
Also, change the class name to `LocalValetDriver` in it.

In the function `frontControllerPath`, add the following code at the top.

```
if ($uri === '/wp') {
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = $sitePath . '/pub/wp';
    return $sitePath . '/pub/wp/index.php';
}
```